# screen reader reads the entire page content in latest chrome 62.

Tags: html, wai-aria, role

In our mobile application, when moving the focus to entire page using talkback, screen reader reads the entire page content. 
latest chrome version: 62
talkback version: 5.2.1.

Please suggest me which aria attribute to be added to avoid this problem. atleast focus should not move to the html body section.